# Issues reading an image as a binary file with fread

Tags: c, fread

I'm new in the world of C programming language and I was trying to read an image as a binary file. Unfortunately, when I tried to read the file I got an incomplete sequence `("\377\330\377", <incomplete sequence \340>)`.
I've already tried to use fread reading only the size of a byte and now I'm trying to use `sizeof(unsigned char)`, but I always get the same incomplete sequence. Here is a part of the code:

```
caratteri **createStruct(unsigned char c[], caratteri car[], caratteri *ptr[], long size) {

    for (long i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        ptr[i] = &car[i];

        car[i].first = &c[i];

        car[i].last = &c[(size - 1 + i) % size];
        car[i].index=i;
    }

    return ptr;
}

int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {

    caratteri *ca = *(caratteri **) a;

    caratteri *cb = *(caratteri **) b;

    unsigned char *c1;

    unsigned char *c2;

    c1 = ca->first;

    c2 = cb->first;

    while (*c1 - *c2 == 0) {

        c1++;

        c2++;
    }

    return (*c1 - *c2);
}

caratteri **bwt(long size, FILE *file) {

    FILE *risultato;
    
    unsigned char *c = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * size);
    
    fread(c, sizeof(unsigned char), size, file);

    caratteri *car = malloc(sizeof(caratteri) * size);

    caratteri **pCaratteri = malloc(sizeof(caratteri *) * size);

    pCaratteri = createStruct(c, car, pCaratteri, size);

    qsort(pCaratteri, size, sizeof(pCaratteri), compare);

    risultato=fopen("risultato","wb");

    for(long i = 0; i < size; i++)

        fputc(*pCaratteri[i]->last,risultato);

    fclose(risultato);

    return pCaratteri;
}
int main() {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("thumbnail.jpg","rb");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Errore di apertura file!");
        exit(2);
    }
    fseek(file, SEEK_SET, SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell(file)+1;
    rewind(file);
    caratteri **car = bwt(size, file);
    FILE *risultato;
    decryptbwt(risultato);
    return 0;
}
```

This is not the full code but I need this part to work properly.
Also, I need this code to work with every kind of file (.txt, .jpg, .png, etc) and I need the \0 character in case of a txt file, that's why I used `ftell(file)+1` but I'm not sure this is appropriate. Anyway, how can I read a file in binary mode avoiding the problem of incomplete sequences?
Thank you for your answers and sorry for the dumb question but I'm new in this world.
I need to take an extra \0 because I'm using an algorithm that needs an end of string character, that's why I'm using ftell with a +1. This algorithm should work with every kind of file so I need to read it correctly and then use the burrows wheeler transform in order to sort the file that I need to compress. Also, I'm not sure that I have to use the fseek in that way but I think there is not another way to get the size of the file.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'incomplete sequences'. If it is a binary file, then you need to know the structure of the file in order to correctly read it, otherwise you would probably not be able to interpret the content correctly (unless you don't care about the content). You may want to start with magic numbers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures).

Comment: Crummy debugger, it thinks displaying the binary data as an utf8 encoded string is a good idea.  It is not, finding invalid utf8 sequences is practically guaranteed.  Do tell us what you use so we can all avoid it.

Comment: What is the intented use of that extra byte? If you want to terminate a string in case of a text file, you need to add the 0 byte after reading. You will not get it from the file. But what is the point of writing 0 to a text file?

Comment: are you sure you want to seek like this `fseek(file, SEEK_SET, SEEK_END);` ?

Comment: The new file should be a copy of the previous one. If it is not things are really weird. But what is your problem exactly: a text editor not being able to display a jpg image? That is not its job...

Comment: I'm debugging using clang on Clion. This algorithm should read every byte, sort it with bwt and then compress it. The problem is that I have this problem of incomplete sequences only with files that are not text files. I tried to change the sorting method in bwt but I always have problems only with files different from a txt file. I was thinking that the problem was fread because the encoding and decoding were working fine until I tried the algorithm with a png, pdf, and jpg file, but maybe there's something else...

Comment: @SergeBallesta the problem is that when I use bwt on it I can't encode it while with text files everything's fine. I did some research and I've found out that maybe this is because of file signature, in fact, the incomplete sequence is always where the file signature should be.

Comment: Ok so the code you have shown is not the code that causes your problem... I am afraid that it will be hard to help you...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Now there is the other part of the code but I think the problem is with fread, because I get incomplete sequences every now and then.